# symfony The controller must return a response (null given)

Tags: php, symfony

Can someone help me understand whats incorrect, 
and how I can fix it? Thanks.

This is my controller:

```
namespace MegBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use MegBundle\Entity\message;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class MegController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/Message/Board", name="MessageBoard")
         */

        public function postMeg()
        {
           $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
            if ($request->request->get("btnOK")) {
                $message = new message($request->request->get("txtName"));
                $message->setMes($request->request->get("txtMes"));
                $entityManager->persist($message);
                $entityManager->flush();
                return $this->redirect('/app_dev.php/Message/Board');
            }
        }
        public function deleteMeg()
        {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
            if ($request->query->get("delete") != null) {
                $id = $request->query->get("delete");
                $message = $entityManager->find('MegBundle:message', $id);
                $entityManager->remove($message);
                $entityManager->flush();
                return $this->redirect('/app_dev.php/Message/Board');
            }
        }
        public function showMeg()
        {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
            if ($request->query->get("DESC") != null) {
                $orderById = "DESC=ID";
                $orderby = 'DESC';
            }

            if ($request->query->get("DESC") == null) {
                $orderById = "ASC=ID";
                $orderby = 'ASC';
            }

            if ($request->query->get("page") == null) {
                $page = 1;
            }

            if ($request->query->get("page") != null) {
                $page = intval($request->query->get("page"));
            }

            $per = 5;
            $start = ($page-1)*$per;
            $query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("r")
                ->from("MegBundle:message", "r")
                ->orderBy('r.id', $orderby)
                ->setFirstResult($start)
                ->setMaxResults($per);
            $data = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
            $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false);
            $count = count($paginator);
            $pages = ceil($count/$per);
            return new Response(include '/usr/share/nginx/html/symfony/Symfony/src/MegBundle/Resources/views/MesView.php');  
        }  
}
```

I´m getting

**The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?**

I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me.

add all the use statements and annotations

Comment: Can you please show the entire contents of the controller including all the `use` statements and annotations?

Comment: @ArleighHix I have added the all use statements and annotations already.

Comment: I think this is not correct : return new Response(include '/usr/share/nginx/html/symfony/Symfony/src/MegBundle/Resources/views/MesView.php');

Comment: please post code of '/usr/share/nginx/html/symfony/Symfony/src/MegBundle/Resources/views/MesView.php' (or MesView.html.php?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: Naming, redirection method and many things need to be corrected in your code.
You only have one return statement in your postMeg() and deletMeg() action. 
Then if the condition for this return is not complete, return value is null. And that is not expected for a controller. You can avoid it by setting a return value if the condition is not complete.